# Normal map not doing what it should, weird shading

Tags: normals

Hi I recently tried baking high poly normals to a low poly mesh for the first time and I encountered a weird issue. My normal map seemed to differ between project files. In my baking project file the normals were exactly how i wanted them, but when trying to apply it to the same mesh in another project the normals were super wonky.

In the below image you can clearly see that the topology of my low poly mesh is somehow impacting the normals even though I've assigned a normal map.

[image: Weird normals]

Here is my normal texture as seen through the viewer node in the same project file. I can see nothing wrong with the texture itself

[image: Normal map view]

...and here is a wireframe view as well

[image: Wireframe]

The UV map is fine

[image: UV map]

Here is the viewport from my baking project file, it's how the normals are supposed to look (if you ignore the small artifacts from the material preview).

[image: Bake project file]

When i baked I used "object space" because it gave me the best result and both projects have non color data selected for the normal texture.

I have no clue how this is happening and I hope some expert can help me! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your normal map has colors that are out of the spectrum, maybe share the high-poly object you've baked (and the low-poly)

Comment: I would have to see a file.  But seeing as you baked exploded, the most likely cause here is that there was some rotation or non-uniform scale involved in putting the revolver back together.  Object space normal maps have no tolerance for those kinds of deformations.  The normal map image represents the remapped object space normals of each sample.  Those are no longer valid under most kinds of deformation.  Like if you rotate the cylinder, the face that used to point in object +Y is still going to be pointing in +Y via the normal map, even though the face has now been rotated to point in +Z.

Comment: I agree with what's mentioned above, however, I also wonder how much the abundance of Tri's and Poles are complicating the mix. Blender does have _some_ tolerance for these things, but smooth shaded objects with rounded (curved) surfaces are normally the worst offenders.

Comment: @Nathan Okay, would applying transforms help? And also how am I supposed to bake details without doing it "exploded". I tried baking everything unexploded but that gave a very poor normal texture as the different meshes in the object intersected with the high poly mesh in some places.

Comment: No, applying transforms after the bake is going to make things worse.  You can bake exploded, but you can't deform (including whole-part rotation or non-uniform scale.)  Once object is baked, you cannot apply rotation or scale, you cannot deform, you cannot leave live modifiers to deform dynamically, you cannot join objects with different rotation or scale.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for the input, I will try redoing the bake without doing any sort of adjustments to the objects themselves and report back.

Comment: I finally figured out what I was doing wrong, turns out I should not be using object space when baking. http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Normal_Map_Technical_Details#Tangent-Space_vs._Object-Space

Also Nathans answer helped me understand how you bake normals better. Thanks for the help everybody.